# Is the null space of a matrix the same after you multiply it by more matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose I know that the nullspace of matrix $P$ is $\mathbf{c}$. Now suppose I multiple $P$ by some matrix $C$, ie. $CP$. Is the nullspace of $CP$ also just $\mathbf{c}$? Or can there be other vectors in the nullspace not equal to $\mathbf{c}$?

Comment: Multiplying by the zero matrix should give you a clue. If zero is not allowed, you can still multiply by matrices which evaluate to zero when multiplied with most vectors.

Comment: Ah that makes sense thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Px=0\Rightarrow CPx=0$ for any $P,~C$. So null space of $P$ is a subset of the null space of $CP$. They are not always equal, for example if $P$ is non-singular and $C$ is singular then since $CP$ is singular, the null space of $CP$ is strictly bigger.